# Unexpected token import on Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, es6-module-loader, rollupjs

I have built an app using GitHub's Electron.  I am using the recommended way of loading modules, the ES6 syntax of:

`import os from 'os'`

After downloading the [boilerplate](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate) the app is working fine.  I have been able to import scripts in the `background.js` file without issue.  Below is how I am loading my custom module:

`import { loadDb } from './assets/scripts/database.js';`

However, when I open a new browser window (`clipboard.html`) within Electron I am then loading a JavaScript file (`clipboard.js`) which in turn tries to `import` modules.  At this point I am getting an `Unexpected token import` error.

My `clipboard.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Electron Boilerplate</title>

    <link href="./stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./assets/scripts/jquery-1.12.1.min.js');
    </script>
    <script src="./assets/scripts/clipboard.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="clipboard">[...]</body></html>
```

My `clipboard.js` file:

```
import { remote } from 'electron'; // native electron module
import { loadDb } from './assets/scripts/database.js';

const electron = require('electron');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { 
    var db = loadDb();
    db.find({ type: 'text/plain' }, function (err, docs) {
        var docsjson = JSON.stringify(docs);
        console.log(docsjson);
    });
});
```

Just to re-iterate, the same code is used within `app.html`, which is my app's main window, and this does not error.

It feels like the main window is initialising something that my `clipboard.html` window isn't (perhaps 'Rollup'?), but there's nothing explicit within my app's code to suggest this.

Comment: Can you post the line number of the error?

Comment: Line 1. Commenting out line 1 gives the same error on line 2. It can't recognise the word 'import' it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run clipboard.js through rollup first. Rollup parses the import statements. You have to modify tasks/build/build.js to do that.

```
var bundleApplication = function () {
    return Q.all([
            bundle(srcDir.path('background.js'), destDir.path('background.js')),
            bundle(srcDir.path('clipboard.js'), destDir.path('clipboard.js')), // Add this line
            bundle(srcDir.path('app.js'), destDir.path('app.js')),
        ]);
};
```

Comment: Well that makes sense in hindsight. Do you think this should be part of the electron docs? I realise it's not electron specific but that's not immediately obvious. I had to dig round to even find out that rollup was even used

Comment: @mikemike It should be part of the docs. I don't know why it was not. Maybe they only expect you to have one entry point.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't. I'm still getting the same error.   I am also getting a message at run time saying "Treating database.js as external dependency", which suggests the file is now passing through rollup.

Comment: I have this working now, it only works if `clipboard.js` is in the root of `/app` (I obviously tried amending the paths in the code).

Answer (score 0):

@user104317 got it right, `clipboard.js` just didn't get "compiled" by `rollup`.

Just wanted to add that in your case, it should have been:

```
var bundleApplication = function () {
    return Q.all([
        bundle(srcDir.path('background.js'), destDir.path('background.js')),
        bundle(srcDir.path('app.js'), destDir.path('app.js')),
        bundle(srcDir.path('assets/scripts/clipboard.js'), destDir.path('assets/scripts/clipboard.js')),
    ]);
};
```

Then you could have left it at `./assets/scripts/clipboard.js`.

If you end up having a lot of independent js files (you shouldn't if you're building a SPA), consider listing them automatically, like done in `./tasks/build/generate_spec_imports.js`